# make search form with js open in new windos

Tags: javascript, forms, window

I want to change the code below so that it opens in a new window. Tried with using "window.open" instead of "window.location.href" without much luck.

```
<form method="get" action="http://www.somesite.com/test/" onSubmit="return false;">
<input type="search" name="q" value="" />
<input type="submit" onClick="window.location.href=this.form.action + this.form.q.value;" />
</form>
```

Comment: `window.open()` works fine: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/turbopipp/764hz1w4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form method="get" action="http://www.somesite.com/test/" onSubmit="return false;">
<input type="search" name="q" value="" />
<input type="submit" onClick="window.open(this.form.action + this.form.q.value); "/>
</form>
```

or

```
<form method="get" action="http://www.somesite.com/test/" target="_blank">
<input type="search" name="q" value="" />
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

I'm not sure which one you need.